# Getting no results back from a form_for in Rails 4.0 Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I am attempting to make a quiz in my rails application and I have looked around and the only gem out there that looked like it did what I want was Survey, but that is not ready for rails 4. Anyway I borrowed the structure that Survey gem creates. So I have Attempts, Surveys, Questions, and Answers

My problem is when I try to pass back which answers were picked to the attempt controller and I am not sure. I am still new to rails so it could be something I am doing / not doing.

#### The View looks like this

```
<% provide(:title, 'Quiz') %>
<h1>Quiz</h1>

<%= form_for(Attempt.new) do |f| %>
    <% @survey = Survey.find(1) %>
    <h3><%= @survey.description  %></h3>
    <br/>
    <% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
        <h4><%= question.text %></h4>
        <br/>
        <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
            <h5><%= f.radio_button question, answer.correct?, :checked => false %>  <%=answer.text%></h5>
            <br/>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

#### The Params currently being returned are

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yCp4rsZfgZDTYK32FYgXTyZSQRQ4DcTWfokbrhImI1Q=", "attempt"=>{}, "commit"=>"Create Attempt", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"attempts"}

#### This is my model structure (Grouped together to make it easier to read)

```
Attempt has many Surveys

Survey belongs to Attempts
Survey has many Questions

Question belongs to Surveys
Question has many Answers

Answer belongs to Questions
```

### Edited: Added in form html

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/attempts" class="new_attempt" id="new_attempt" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="jOQCSERK6LKWwKwIprv0fhn62W+9T13WSXss8oswyFo="></div>
    <h3>Tests if I can register individuals</h3>
    <br>
        <h4>Paul's Favorite Color</h4>
        <br>
            <h5><input id="attempt_#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d11e8&gt;_false" name="attempt[#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d11e8&gt;]" type="radio" value="false">  Green</h5>
            <br>
            <h5><input id="attempt_#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d11e8&gt;_false" name="attempt[#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d11e8&gt;]" type="radio" value="false">  Blue</h5>
            <br>
            <h5><input id="attempt_#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d11e8&gt;_true" name="attempt[#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d11e8&gt;]" type="radio" value="true">  Teal</h5>
            <br>
        <h4>Paul's Age</h4>
        <br>
            <h5><input id="attempt_#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d0b80&gt;_false" name="attempt[#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d0b80&gt;]" type="radio" value="false">  20</h5>
            <br>
            <h5><input id="attempt_#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d0b80&gt;_true" name="attempt[#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d0b80&gt;]" type="radio" value="true">  21</h5>
            <br>
            <h5><input id="attempt_#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d0b80&gt;_false" name="attempt[#&lt;Question:0x007f41704d0b80&gt;]" type="radio" value="false">  22</h5>
            <br>
    <div class="actions">
      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Attempt">
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: Quiz Page]

Comment: This does not look like a good rails view, there are no bind variables between the view and the controller, `Attempt.new` should be defined on your controller method as an instance variable e.g `@attempt` `@survey = Survey.find(1)` should also be in your controller (even though looks like something wrong)

Comment: @bjhaid I know that `@survey = Survey.find(1)` shouldn't be there I was just trying to do a PoC, hence why it is hard coded in. May I ask what you mean by binding variables between the view and controller? Sorry I am still new RoR.

Comment: The code you provided is not quite sufficient to judge if you have been doing anything wrong. Please add the HTML you end up with from the `form_for` (such that we can see the action and the field ids) and the controller action the request is routed to.

Comment: @Patru Just added this html for the form_for

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you posted really makes it clear that something "un-railsish" is going on here. If you call the `form_for`-helper method in the way you did it it will create a `FormBuilder` object which will build the actual form, so we have to check the parameters of the `radio_button` in the `FormBuilder` class (in Rubyspeak that might also be [`FormBuilder#radio_button`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-radio_button)). There we find

```
radio_button(method, tag_value, options = {})
```

so the three parameters of the method rails expects are the *name* of the *method* of the object the form should operate on (which in your case would be your `Attempt.new` object). The most *usual* thing to pass at this point is a symbol with the method name, but as you provided a `Question`-object rails is trying to be forgiving and converts whatever it is passed into a `String` (probably using the `to_s` method). As you do not seem to have implemented `to_s` in your `Question` class the default implementation of `Object` will kick in to provide a "description" of your object with a class name and an address in angular brackets. As the angular brackets would confuse the HTML-parser these are gently escaped for you and you end up with messed up `id` and `name` attributes of your `input` elements. This will most certainly confuse the rails `params` parser when the HTTP POST-request is passed back and you end up with what you posted.

It is not really obvious how to fix this without knowing more about your `Model` classes, but most probably you want to use a nested form to solve this in the right way. This is not something I can do from the top of my head, but you can check out this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Attempt instance variable in AttemptsConroller on creation:

```
def new
  @attempt = Attempt.new
end
```

In your view use the instance just created:

```
<%= form_for(@attempt) do |f| %>
```

That should do the trick if I did not completely miss the problem at hand.

Comment: No, that's not the problem, it is that it is not returning any values in the params when I try to feed in the values from page

Comment: After reading your code again, I have two other questions: a) Model - are you sure you want "Attempt has many Surveys" instead of "Survey has many Attempts"? b) In your form you "only create" a form for an Attempt but you do not use that variable. Instead you lookup a survey and create your form from the survey attribs. Since you are not altering the new Attempt instance in ANY way it is correctly returned as "attempt"=>{}.